# OnBindViewHolder not called unless I save a file first

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview

**Update #2**

Thanks to AgentP for hinting my problem . I have fixed this issue by making this change inside showImages() :

(Also created a global reference field String path; in the same activity) :

```
    private void showImages(){
    
        // Added following two lines :
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(this); // + added
        path = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).toString(); // + added
    
        //  String path = DrawingActivity.path; // - removed
        allFilesPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        allFilesPaths = listAllFiles(path);
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.galleryRecycleViewId);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    
        ArrayList<Cell> cells = prepareData();
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cells);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    }
```

---

**Update**

Apparently I have a static string that is only set inside save image method . It's purpose is to give image folder path to the show images method. I'm trying to provide path to my showImages() method via other means now .

---

**Old**

I have a gallery activity that displays images from a folder with recycler view .

When I start my app the gallery is empty despite having images in the folder .

When I go to my drawing activity , save an image and return to gallery activity it shows all images without problems .

I placed a log inside onbindviewholder method and it only executes after I save an image.

What functionality is missing for image adapter to see exiting files and what does image saving do to make it find them when executed ?

(Also I remember when I wrote the save image method that it wanted me to do @SuppressLint("WrongThread") , but now it works without it)

Debug info when opening gallery without saving a file in drawing activity:

- ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.myapp-2/lib/x86_64
- Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
- Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
- D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
- I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
- W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

Methods involved in displaying images inside Gallery Activity :

```
    List <Cell> allFilesPaths;
        
        // on create calls show images after checking if read storage permission is good
        
     private void showImages(){
            // this is the current problem line , 
            // I need a way to give path of my image folder to this method
            // Check SaveImage() method below to see how it is initially set
            // path is a global static field inside drawing activity
            String path = DrawingActivity.path;
            allFilesPaths = new ArrayList<>();
            allFilesPaths = listAllFiles(path);
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.galleryRecycleViewId);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    
            ArrayList<Cell> cells = prepareData();
            ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cells);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
        }
    
        private ArrayList<Cell> prepareData(){
            ArrayList<Cell> allImages = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Cell c : allFilesPaths){
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.setTitle(c.getTitle());
                cell.setPath(c.getPath());
                allImages.add(cell);
            }
            return allImages;
        }
    
        private List<Cell> listAllFiles(String pathName){
            List<Cell> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
            if(pathName != null){
                File file = new File(pathName);
                File[] files = file.listFiles();
                if(files != null){
                    for (File f : files){
                        Cell cell = new Cell();
                        cell.setTitle(f.getName());
                        cell.setPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
                        allFiles.add(cell);
                    }
                }
            }
            return allFiles;
        }
```

Inside my Image Adapter :

```
private ArrayList<Cell> galleryList;
private Context context;
private static final String TAG = "ImageAdapter";

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cell> galleryList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);
    return new ImageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + galleryList.size());
    setImageFromPath(galleryList.get(position).getPath(), holder.img);
    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String path = galleryList.get(position).getPath();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context ,ImagePreview.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("imagePath",path);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return galleryList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
}

private void setImageFromPath(String path, ImageView image){
    File imgFile = new File(path);

    try {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imgFile));
            image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            //            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewSelect);
            //            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

method inside drawing activity that saves images :

```
   public void saveImage() {
       ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getContext());
       String filename = "img" + System.currentTimeMillis();
       File directory = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       path = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).toString();
       File myPath = new File(directory, filename + ".jpg");

       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
       try {
           fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }finally {
           try {
               fileOutputStream.flush();
               fileOutputStream.close();
           }catch (IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: what is DrawingActivity.path ? what value does it holds ?

Comment: I think you might just have solved my question .. It's a static field that is set once I save an image .
path = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).toString();
Apparently it is never set unless I call this method . I think I should find a way to make it globally set somehow ..

Comment: I have solved the problem , thanks for helping :) . Noted my changes in an update .

Comment: General Wau if you find the answer to your question add it as answer... i.e answer your own question by yourself and accept it. So that others will know it is solved and in future, it will help others also. BTW you are welcome and Happy Coding :)

Comment: Might as well answer yourself so I can mark it as solution . You hinted the problem :)
If it adds credit or points etc ..

Comment: Welcome @GeneralWau =) 
As @AgentP said, you can answer your own question and accepts it. That will make it easier for future visitors to understand how you solved your problem.
I'm not sure I've understood the changes you described in the latest update. It would be super useful to provide the whole new `showImages()` implementation.

Comment: Roger that , I'll rework my Update#2 to make it easier :) , AgentP posted an answer I accepted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the variable `DrawingActivity.path` in `showImages()` have some value inside of it. It might not have initialized properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the **ViewHolder** Class constructor instead

```
setImageFromPath(galleryList.get(getLayoutPosition()).getPath(), holder.img);
```

Comment: I fixed it by instantiating context wrapper and then gettng the folder path from it . Then I fed it directly in the show images method .

path = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).toString();

I tried your suggestion too but the issue still persisted for some reason :)